# htaccess how to get two varibales only in three url text

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hello i have a little problem

i have this url 
categories/4/esmail/jeddah

i need to GET only return value (4,jeddah)

for note esmail is name of categories it may change if we change category number , so it is not fixed

i try this htaccess line

```
RewriteRule ^categorie/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)+$ ads.php?categorie=$1&area=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

in this simple i need to set

```
$categorie = 4 , area = jeddah
```

any help

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
RewriteRule ^categorie/([0-9]+)/([A-z0-9_-]*)/(.*)$ ads.php?categorie=$1&area=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

For you to get, it would be:

```
$categorie = $_GET["categorie"]; $area = $_GET["area"];
```

**I think that's what you need ...**

Comment: thanks for replay , but i got this Array ( [categorie] => 4 [area] => esmail ) , i need area to be Jeddah not esmail

Comment: Then replace the "$2" with "$3" (it will solve your problem)